# How to find the iTunes Store link of an installed App?

Tags: itunes, ios, applications, ios-appstore

I have one of the numerous flashlight apps that I wanted to recommend to a friend.

[image]

**What is the easiest way to retrieve the iTunes Store link from my already installed iOS App ?**

The info window was helpful as I could find the App by searching for the name of the developer.

And apparently the ID can also be found in the `iTunesMetadata.plist` inside the `.ipa` file.

For this App its: http://itunes.apple.com/app/id384021568

Is there an easier, more straight-forward way to retrieve the iTunes Store link ?

Answer (score 1):

Google your app by name. The iTunes preview page should be pretty close to the top of the list. You can send that link to your friend.

Comment: A least google sometimes seems to produce better results than the iTunes search. But that's not what I'm looking for. Once you found the App in iTunes (or the iOS App Store) you can get the link by right-clicking the icon or as [Matt](http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/16463/matt-love) wrote via "Tell a Friend". I'm looking for a similar way (in iTunes, or rather without using a search field) to get the link for _installed_ Apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to do this from your iOS device, you can locate the app in the App Store, scroll down to the bottom and select "Tell a Friend". This will allow you to email your friend with the link and a brief description of the app.

Good luck!